# Comparing tow large files line by line

Tags: python, linux, file, iterator

I was wondering if there is any efficient way to compare 2 large files line by line.

**File 1**

```
2
3
2
```

**File 2**

```
2 | haha
3 | hoho
4 | hehe
```

I am just taking the first character of each file and comparing against them. Currently i am using a very naive method of iterating through them in a double for loop.

**Like**

```
For i in file 1: 
    line number = 0
    For j in file 2: 
        loop until line number == counter else add 1 to line number 
        Compare line 1 
    increase counter
```

Reading both files into memory is not an option. I am using python on linux but i am open to both bash solutions and python script solutions

Comment: So you want to compare each line with *the same line* from the other file? `zip` them!

Comment: @Jornsharpe i cannot zip them as i cannot load them into memory

Comment: If you're using 2.x, `itertools.izip` them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
diff <(cut -c 1 file1.txt) <(cut -c 1 file2.txt)
```

[`diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) is the tool you use to compare files' lines. You can use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (anonymous pipe) to compare a version of each file only containing the first character (using [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)).

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the two files and iterate them together.

```
f1 = open('File 1')
f2 = open('File 2')

flag = True 

for file1_line, file2_line in zip(f1, f2):
  if file1_line[0] != file2_line[0]:
    flag = False
    break

print(flag)
```